# text size and background color not changing ..not changing on changing the xml code also..image link is added on bottom

Tags: android, android-studio, android-adapter

I have created a custom adapter... the text size is not changing...code shows no error...runs fine on my device ...color is shown on design in split mode in adroid studio...but on mobile there is no color plain white bg
can't find something similar..pls help
Earthquakeactivity.java

```
package com.example.earthquake_udacity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class EarthquakeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final String LOG_TAG = EarthquakeActivity.class.getName();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.earthquake_activity);

        // Create a fake list of earthquake locations.
        ArrayList<list_data_type> earthquakes = new ArrayList<>();
        earthquakes.add(new list_data_type("11/2/21","4","San Francisco"));
        earthquakes.add(new list_data_type("11/2/20","5","London"));
        earthquakes.add(new list_data_type("11/3/21","3","Tokyo"));
        earthquakes.add(new list_data_type("11/4/88","2","Mexico City"));
//        earthquakes.add(new list_data_type("6","Moscow",3/2/21));
//        earthquakes.add(new list_data_type("5.3","Rio de Janeiro",5/12/17));
//        earthquakes.add(new list_data_type("3.1","Paris",4/8/18));

        // Find a reference to the {@link ListView} in the layout
        ListView earthquakeListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

        // Create a new {@link ArrayAdapter} of earthquakes
        itemsadapter adapter = new itemsadapter(this, earthquakes ,R.layout.list_item_layout);

        // Set the adapter on the {@link ListView}
        // so the list can be populated in the user interface
        earthquakeListView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

earthquake_activity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ListView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

list_data_type.java

```
package com.example.earthquake_udacity;

public class list_data_type
{
    private String location;
    private String date;
    private String magnitude;

    public list_data_type( String date,String magnitude,String location) {
        this.location = location;
        this.date = date;
        this.magnitude = magnitude;
    }

    public String getLocation() {
        return location;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public String getMagnitude() {
        return magnitude;
    }
}
```

itemsadapter.java

```
package com.example.earthquake_udacity;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class itemsadapter extends ArrayAdapter {
    public itemsadapter(@NonNull Context context, ArrayList<list_data_type> obj, int resource) {
        super(context, resource,obj);
    }


    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // Check if the existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
        View listItemView = convertView;
        if (listItemView == null) {
            listItemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(
                    R.layout.list_item_layout, parent, false);
        }
        list_data_type currentItem = (list_data_type) getItem(position);

        TextView mag_tv = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.magnitude_id);
        mag_tv.setText(currentItem.getMagnitude());

        TextView loc_tv = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.location_id);
        loc_tv.setText(currentItem.getLocation());

        TextView date_tv = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.date_id);
        date_tv.setText(currentItem.getDate());

        return listItemView;
    }
}
```

list_item_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/teal_200"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textSize="42sp"
        android:id="@+id/magnitude_id"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textSize="42sp"
        android:id="@+id/location_id"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textSize="42sp"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:id="@+id/date_id"
        />


</LinearLayout>
```

manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.earthquake_udacity">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Earthquake_udacity">
        <activity android:name=".EarthquakeActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

themes.xml

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
 <style name="Theme.Practica1" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Primary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/purple_500</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/purple_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
        <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
        <!-- Status bar color. -->
        <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>
</resources>
```

I have not changed anything else...other things are as they should be by default
and thanks for help.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fa4uw.jpg)

Comment: Sometimes ide cache is problematic, did you try `invalidate your caches and restart`?

Comment: yes sir..i saw this solution somewhere and tried but it didnt worked

Answer (score 0):

Be sure your Theme is light like this one:

```
<style name="Theme.Practica1" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
```

And color_primary is not black.

In list_item.layout.xml file remove background of date_id TextView :

```
android:background="@color/cardview_dark_background"
```

Also remove LinearLayout background:

```
android:background="@color/white"
```

Comment: thanks sir...the bg changed to white after changing this line...but still on changing the code in list_item_layout.xml file...the textsize and bg for each textview still not changing

Comment: In list_item.layout.xml file you have date_id TextView remove :
`android:background="@color/cardview_dark_background"`
also remove :
`android:background="@color/white"` in LinearLayout

Comment: update your answer and put these codes there @Sajad

Comment: no sir ,it did not change...i have changed the code suggestions u made in ques code also

Comment: i have also updated android studio..so that there are no api or plugin updates left

Comment: i have made other small projects on same android studio...in which  textsize and bg color changes according to xml..but in this one it's not changing

Comment: Remove `android:background="@color/white"` in linear layout from list_item_layout.xml

Comment: still same sir @SajadHosseini

Comment: @Psycho...still problem persists sir

Comment: don't know what it was....copied the same files and pasted to another project...and it worked like nothing was wrong...thanks for giving your time